# How to take all sub-strings in a string that are combinations of specified characters only

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

```
"tgtaaaaacaagaaaaacatggaatgtataatactataaataaaaaaagtaggaagaagaaccaaaaca\
 aagggcgttttaaagagagacgaat"
```

based on the above string (a DNA sequence) I wish to extract sub-strings of length $>5$ characters that compose of consecutive `"a"`'s or `"t"`'s and not include `"c"` and `"g"`.

For example, few of the substrings are `"taaaaa"`, `"tataat"`, `"tataaat"` $\ldots$ so on and so forth.

I tried using `StringCases` but I cannot identify a pattern for the `StringCase` function that I can employ to select only sub-strings that are combinations of `"a"`'s or `"t"`'s.

Moreover, I would be grateful if someone can direct me to a place where I can study more about how to use patterns for strings in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `Alternatives` (`|`) and `Repeated` in `StringCases`.

```
dna = "tgtaaaaacaagaaaaacatggaatgtataatactataaataaaaaaagtaggaagaagaaccaaaacaaagggcgttttaaagagagacgaat";

StringCases[dna, Longest@Repeated["a" | "t", {6, Infinity}]]

(* {"taaaaa", "tataata", "tataaataaaaaaa", "ttttaaa"} *)
```

You can learn more from the [String Patterns tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringPatterns.html) in the documentation.

Hope this helps.

PS: You may also want to take a look at the [`GenomeData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GenomeLookup.html) function and other [Life Sciences & Medicine](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LifeSciencesAndMedicineDataAndComputation.html) functions in Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you so much !! works great. I was trying to create a pattern and that was what was preventing me from searching for Repeated ! Thanks again

Comment: The regex version: `StringCases[dna, RegularExpression["[at]{6,}"]]`